# Why changing the status code after writing to the body returns 504?

Tags: c#, owin, asp.net-core

In ASP.NET 5 I've seem that the following code gives an error 504 in the response:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.Use((next) => {

            return async (context) => {

                context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World");
                context.Response.StatusCode = 201;
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Status code changed");

            };

        });
    }
}
```

I know we shouldn't change the status code in this arbitrary manner, but my question here is: why changing it gives a problem? The fact is that, commenting the line that changes the status code, and using `Response.WriteAsync` twice, doesn't give any kind of problem, but changing the status code gives.

When we do it this returns a 504 status code. I believe it has to do with the way the response is sent to the client. It happens because when we call `Respose.WriteAsync` the response message starts being sent already? What's the reason for this error to occur?

Comment: Why are you writing to the response in a `Configure` method?  Have you tried running the code synchronously to make sure that's not the real issue?

Comment: Is your question why 504 and not generic 500? (it looks like you understand that what you are doing is invalid and expect code to fail already)... or you simply disagree with the fact that "attempt to change headers after body sent causes exception"?

Comment: @DStanley It's not something to use in production, I was just studying how the middlewares work and found this issue when chaining then together in a wrong manner. Then I got curious about why this behavior happens and asked here. Now, since the Response has just one `WriteAsync` method I don't know how can I do it synchronously.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, intuitively I know this is invalid, but I'm trying to really understand *why* it is invalid. I mean, when doing `Response.WriteAsync` the response is already being sent? If not, why changing the headers causes exception?

Comment: My point is, since 504 is a "gateway timeout" error I would investigate whether or not changing the status code is the problem, or there is something wrong with how you're calling the code asynchronously.

Comment: "I mean, when doing `Response.WriteAsync` the response is already being sent?" Is that a question? The answer is yes, as you already seem to know. Secondly, assuming `Response` is `OwinResponse`, it should also have a `Write` method, which should allow you test it synchronously, as @DStanley has suggested.

Comment: @DStanley, I've tried it out synchronously now, but the result is the same, after calling `Response.Body.Write` if I change the status code the 504 error is returned.

Comment: Headers are sent the moment content is written to the body...so if you are setting the status code again, then probably an exception is being thrown in the middleware to indicate this...BTW this exception would cause the 504 that you are seeing...you can put a try-catch block to capture the exception message and see what it says..

Comment: Thanks @KiranChalla, it was exactly that. Using a try-catch block the exception was caught and it says: "A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.dll Headers already sent." Would you like to make your comment one answer?

Comment: Cool!..sure will do..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Headers are sent the moment content is written to the response body stream and so you cannot change the headers again...so if you are setting the status code again, then probably an exception is being thrown in the middleware to indicate this...

BTW this exception would cause the 504 that you are seeing(like currently there is no response buffering layer which could catch these kind of exceptions and returns a 500 Internal Server with an error message)...you can put a try-catch block to capture the exception message and see what it says..